# Need help to close my SVG Christmas box using CSS3 animation and transform

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following box:

```css
@keyframes closeLeft {
  0% {
    transform: skew(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: skew(-251deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: skew(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes closeRight {
  0% {
    transform: skew(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: skew(251deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: skew(0deg);
  }
}


#arm-box-upcover-left {
  animation: closeLeft 3s linear infinite;
  transform-origin: 570px 623px;
}
#arm-box-upcover-right {
  animation: closeRight 3s linear infinite;
  transform-origin: 570px 623px;
}
```

```html
<svg id="city-total-v2" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" enable-background="new 0 0 1000 1000" xml:space="preserve">
        <g id="arm-box">
          <polygon fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#07002C" points="537.21,626.07 553.15,615.79 535.62,611.12
         519.09,621.32 537.21,626.07   "/>
          <polygon fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#7C0A67" points="519.47,620.96 520.23,639.55 537.88,644.29
            537.13,625.71 519.47,620.96   "/>
          <polygon fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#07002C" points="536.69,625.78 537.92,644.25 553.97,633.84
            552.98,615.43 536.69,625.78   "/>
          <polygon id="arm-box-upcover-right" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#7C0A67" points="551.74,617.11 552.1,599.36 534.57,594.68
            533.62,612.36 551.74,617.11   "/>
          <polygon id="arm-box-upcover-left" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#B21255" points="537.09,626.3 526.49,612.56 508.96,607.88
         518.97,621.56 537.09,626.3   "/>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

I want to be able to close it. I have played with `skew` and `transform-origin`, but I wasn't able to perfectly close it and open it.

Do you know what transformation I need to apply in order to close my box?

Comment: You're not being specific enough how the box should be closed.

Comment: When close, it should be a cube, when open, it should be flaps open (flaps are the animated part of the snippet)

Comment: I can see that, what I mean is that 2 sides out of 6 are open, how should the side one be closed, from left or right? I'd rather suggest that you close it and leave only the upper one, which can also be split in two parts, more realistic example.

Comment: I don't understand Your question. only 1 sides out of 6 is open. Like a moving house box, you don't open it with two side. But, you have two flaps by sides. I want to open the box by the top side. Is this still unclear ? If you'r suggestion was different, I'll be glad to get more details.